# Linux, Making simple http web server in C

Tags: c, linux, http

```
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SMALL_BUF 100

char response1[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>     <title>My Web Page</title> </head> <body>      
<h1>Welcome to My Web Page!</h1> </body> </html>\r\n";

char response2[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>     <title>My Web Page</title> </head> <body>      
<h1>Welcome to My Web Page2!</h1> </body> </html>\r\n";

char* content_type(char* file);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
   socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(client_addr);
   int fd_server, fd_client;
   char buf[2048];
   int on = 1;
   char indexhtml[]="index.html";
   char queryhtml[]="query.html";
   char *get;
   char *domain;
   char *none;
   char *message;
   char *state;
   fd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if(fd_server < 0)
   {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(1);
   }

   setsockopt(fd_server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(int));

   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   server_addr.sin_port = htons(50814);

   if (bind(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
   {
        perror("bind error");
        close(fd_server);
        exit(1);
   }

   if (listen(fd_server, 10) == -1)
   {
       perror("listen error");
       close(fd_server);
       exit(1);
   }

   while(1)
   {
        fd_client = accept(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_len);

        if(fd_client == -1)
        {
                perror("connection failed\n");
                continue;
        }

        if (fd_client > 0)
{
                printf("got client connection\n");
        }


        strcpy(state,strtok(message," /"));
        strcpy(domain,strtok(NULL," /"));

        printf("state: %s\n",state);
        printf("domain: %s\n",domain);
        if(strcmp(state,get)==0)
        {
                if(strcmp(domain,indexhtml)==0||strcmp(domain,none)==0)
            {
                    write(fd_client,response1, sizeof(response1)-1);
            }
                else if(strcmp(domain,queryhtml)==0)
            {
                    write(fd_client,response2, sizeof(response2)-1);
            }

  }
}
   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to create a simple web server in c with Linux that runs with localhost.
when I type local address:portnumber I want to show "my webpage!"
and when I type local address:portnumber/index.html, i want to show "my webpage!" also, and then when I type local address:portnumber/query.html, I want to show "my webpage2!" Howeverm I am keep facing with segmentation fault... Please help me out.. Thank you all for helping me out!!

Comment: You start solving crashes in your program by finding out where they happen using a *debugger*. Please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Another good start would be to not have any *uninitialized pointers!* And making sure you don't dereference null pointers!